# Find the smallest number without using inbuilt function

Tags: python

```
num=[4,5,6,3,1,77,-3,-5,-6,-20,4,7,-200,5,7]
n=0

for i in range(len(num)):
    for j in range(i+1):
        if num[j]<num[i]:
               n=num[j]
print(n)
```

I want to find the smallest number but I am getting 7 as the output.
What is the possible mistake am I doing?

---

Comment: What is your reasoning for a nested loop?

Comment: Also, think of how you would solve it if you were doing this by hand.

Comment: @navneethc for comparing the values.

Comment: Why do you want to compare values with a nested loop? Think along the lines of the second question.

Comment: do I have to take a temporary variable?

Comment: I'm surprised this even runs, `range(i+1)` should generate an out of bounds error.

Comment: @MarkRansom `i` is always valid, and `j` never gets bigger than `i`.

Comment: @chepner of course you're right, silly me.  But the double loop is exactly the reason why it's giving the wrong answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think it is an example of two wrongs making a right! Two off-by-one errors in nice juxtaposition. Albeit for no reason. Probably trial-and-error, haha!

Comment: so basically my mistake is running two for loops?

Comment: @user20666007 - just do a google here in S/O - you will find tons of answer.

Comment: Just read again @MarkRansom excellent post. Then you should able to solve it.  And maybe run it here - https://pythontutor.com/  to see each step actions.

Answer (score 1):

The way you should do it in Python is:  `n = min(num)`.  Since you were asked to do it without using a function, this is obviously a homework assignment designed to teach you how to do this simple kind of operation.

When I run your code, I don't get `7` as a result, I get `5`.  Adding a couple of debugging statements shows me that this occurs when j=13 and i=14, which makes sense since `num[13] < num[14]`.  You should have been able to add some code to reach the same conclusion.

Not only is your code giving the wrong answer, it's very slow to do so.  You're comparing every number to every other number, which you don't need to do.  All you need to do is compare every number to the one you currently believe to be the smallest.

Comment: Excellent analysis.  - *"All you need to do is compare every number to the one currently samllest..."* +1

Answer (score 0):

Here there is no need of nested for loop . This can be solved in this way :

```
numbers = [5, 3, 8, 2, 9, 1]

smallest = numbers[0]  # assume the first number is the smallest

for num in numbers:
    if num < smallest:
        smallest = num

print(smallest)
```

Alternative way :

```
num = [4,5,6,3,1,77,-3,-5,'hello',-6,-20,4,7,-200,5,7]
smallest = None

for i in range(len(num)):
    if isinstance(num[i], int):
        if smallest is None or num[i] < smallest:
            smallest = num[i]

if smallest is None:
    print("The list is empty or contains only non-numeric values")
else:
    print(smallest)
```

Comment: this code fails if list is empty

Comment: Yes, user is asking for smallest number that's why i gave reference . The other validation like postive and negative type , integer or string , empty etc. user can add as per his convenience.

Comment: of course, but in his example the smallest number is -200, and in your code is 1 :)

Answer (score -1):

Several mistakes

#### Start with your answer as one of the values, not zero

Otherwise if your values are all positive, you will be wrong

#### Only search through your data once

You need a single loop not two nested loops

#### Keep track of the smallest, as you go

Two more free tips!

- Use better variable names
- You can use Python's ability to loop through the values, rather than have an index (i or j, and then look up the value using the index and the array).

```
numbers=[4,5,6,3,1,77,-3,-5,-6,-20,4,7,-200,5,7]

smallest_so_far = numbers[0]

for number in numbers:
        if number<smallest_so_far:
               smallest_so_far = number

print(smallest_so_far)
```

Comment: Thanks for doing their homework for them.

Comment: Yes, it does look like homework, doesn't it? Hehehe. I was a kid once too. At least I gave them some tips! 8-)

Comment: You could have given the tips without the copy/paste answer.

Comment: Agreed! I am a big softie.

Answer (score -1):

To protect youself from errors if you have an empty list, you can initialize `n` to be the largest possible number `inf`

```
num = [4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 77, -3, -5, -6, -20, 4, 7, -200, 5, 7]
n = float('inf')

for i in range(len(num)):
    if num[i] < n:
        n = num[i]

print(n)
```

Comment: +1 for starting with n=infinity. Other answers starting with the 0th element may break if `num` is an empty list.

Answer (score -3):

Here is some adjusted code.  The double for loop is going to be very inefficient.  Also setting n=0 means that if your list was all greater than 0, you would never find the least in your list.

```
num=[4,5,6,3,1,77,-3,-5,-6,-20,4,7,-200,5,7]
n=num[0]

for i in range(len(num)):
    if n>num[i]:
        n=num[i]
print(n)
```